# Can't find logs in Elastic search docker container

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, docker

I'm running the public elastic search container with following arguments:

```
docker run -d -v /elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name my_elastic_search elasticsearch:2.4.1 -Des.cluster.name="elastic_search_name"
```

I'm interested in getting the logs but I've had no luck finding them. Where are they supposed to be located? I've looked in `/var/log/elasticsearch` and `/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs` and both of these directories are empty

Comment: It's weird. I reviewed its Dockerfile, the log should be in ```/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs```. Could you check the ```path.logs``` in the ```elasticsearch.yml```?

Comment: Just to ensure - did you look for the logs from _inside_ the container?

Comment: If path.logs is not specified, is logging disabled? All I have in my config is `network.host: 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 5):

The default logging configuration in the `2.4.x` tagged docker containers does not enable file logging. A solution is to map the elasticsearch `config` folder to your own volume containing a `logging.yml` file  **(and an `elasticsearch.yml` file and a `scripts` folder!)**

`docker run -d -v /elasticsearch/config:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config -v /elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name my_elastic_search elasticsearch:2.4.1 -Des.cluster.name="elastic_search_name"`

Your logging configuration must contain the required file appenders, such as the default shown here:

```yaml
# you can override this using by setting a system property, for example -Des.logger.level=DEBUG
es.logger.level: INFO
rootLogger: ${es.logger.level}, console, file
logger:
  # log action execution errors for easier debugging
  action: DEBUG

  # deprecation logging, turn to DEBUG to see them
  deprecation: INFO, deprecation_log_file

  # reduce the logging for aws, too much is logged under the default INFO
  com.amazonaws: WARN
  # aws will try to do some sketchy JMX stuff, but its not needed.
  com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport: ERROR
  com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics: ERROR

  org.apache.http: INFO

  # gateway
  #gateway: DEBUG
  #index.gateway: DEBUG

  # peer shard recovery
  #indices.recovery: DEBUG

  # discovery
  #discovery: TRACE

  index.search.slowlog: TRACE, index_search_slow_log_file
  index.indexing.slowlog: TRACE, index_indexing_slow_log_file

additivity:
  index.search.slowlog: false
  index.indexing.slowlog: false
  deprecation: false

appender:
  console:
    type: console
    layout:
      type: consolePattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %.10000m%n"

  # Use the following log4j-extras RollingFileAppender to enable gzip compression of log files. 
  # For more information see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html
  #file:
    #type: extrasRollingFile
    #file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log
    #rollingPolicy: timeBased
    #rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz
    #layout:
      #type: pattern
      #conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  deprecation_log_file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}_deprecation.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  index_search_slow_log_file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}_index_search_slowlog.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  index_indexing_slow_log_file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}_index_indexing_slowlog.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"
```